# TagMapping the AudienceEditor control not working

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I needed to add text to the `AudienceEditor` Control everywhere and so I created a custom

```
class inheriting from `Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.AudienceEditor` class 

   public class AudienceEditorText : Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.AudienceEditor
   {
        protected override void OnPreRender(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnPreRender(e);
            Label lblText = new Label();
            lblText.ID = "Note";
            lblText.Visible = true;
            lblText.Text = "Text Needs to be changed";
            lblText.Attributes.Add("style", "color: red");
            Controls.Add(lblText);          
        }

        protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnInit(e);
        } 

        protected override void CreateChildControls()
        {
            base.CreateChildControls();
        }

        protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnLoad(e);

        }
    }
```

and added the following tags in web.config

```
 <tagMapping>        
    <add tagType="Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.AudienceEditor, Microsoft.Office.Server, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" mappedTagType="Hub.AudienceEditorProject.AudienceEditorText, Hub.AudienceEditorProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=df1f6b11d06cf6ca" />
  </tagMapping>
```

I was expecting the `AudienceEditor` control to be replaced by the new class in the `EditForm.aspx` and `NewForm.aspx`, but this is not working. I tried to debug the custom class, but execution doesn't enter the project, which means the `AudienceEditor` control doesn't get replaced.

The view source tells that the Audience field is rendered by the Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.FieldTypes.SPFieldTargetTo class, which contains the Microsoft.Office.Server.WebControls.FieldTypes.SpFieldTaretToControl, which in turn houses the AudienceEditor control. I have tried inheriting from all these 3 controls and tagmapped them, but it is simply not working.

Just to test I have mapped the TextBox control too and that works fine on the same page. It also comes into Debug. But the AudienceEditor is simply not working.

Answer (score 0):

All I can think of is that you are seeing this behaviour because the [tagMappings are applied at compile time](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164641.aspx), and the parent control that instantiates the AudienceEditor as a child control is already compiled into it's own dll.

Some alternative solutions that I think would do the job.

- use css to display an image with your text as a background image,
  positioned where you want it.
- use javascript to inject the text when
  the document has been loaded in the browser
- use control adapters to
  control rendering of the Audience Editor control (not very easy to
  deploy when we're talking SharePoint)